# Omit properties from subclass and leave new declared properties

Tags: typescript

I have Model class that contains many other properties and class that inherited from this Model class

```js
export default class Item extends Model {
  declare id: number
  declare name: string
  declare price: number
}
```

typeof Item would be something like that:

`{id: number, name: string, price: number, save: (...) => ..., create: (...) => ..., etc...}`

There are properties like `save` and `create` from Model

All I want is type that contains only new defined properties from Item

`{id: number, name: string, price: number}` (properties from Model is removed)

I already tried something like this

```js
type ModelFields<T extends Model> = Omit<T, keyof typeof Model>
```

But that doesn't work, at least because IDE (WebStorm) includes properties from Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ModelFields type was wrong, it was should be

```js
type ModelFields<T extends Model> = Omit<T, keyof Model>
```